# How to distinguish what caused rendering of React component: something from the inside or from the outside of the component?

Tags: reactjs

I have two nested react components: `Outer` and `Inner`. Whenever I call `setState` of `Inner`, `render` of inner component gets invoked. Also, whenever I call `setState` of outer component, `render` functions of both outer and inner components gets invoked.
I would like to distinguish those two cases and detect what coused rendering of the inner component. My `render` function of `Inner` should behave differently depending on that. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the fact that the componentWillReceiveProps is only called when the component is receiving new props (check out here: http://busypeoples.github.io/post/react-component-lifecycle/), not when setState is called, and importantly they don't even have to be different props than the existing ones (per https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops). So you should be able to do something along the lines of

```
componentWillReceiveProps() {
  this.setState({parentUpdated: true});
}

render() {
  if (this.state.parentUpdated) {
    // Render one way
  } else {
    // Render the other way
  }
}
```

Although you would also need to unset that after the render somehow, or just ensure that every call to this.setState also includes {parentUpdated: false}.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is controlling the `Update` stage in `Inner` Component's life cycle. 
You can check `componentWillUpdate` stage in [doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillupdate) to control `Inner`'s behaviours when `Outer` is re-rendered.

Comment: `componentWillUpdate` will be called in both cases, with the same parameters. I don't see how this can be useful

Comment: It has `nextProps` and `nextState` properties which normally decides the `render` method's behaviours. You can compare your old `props` and `states` with the new one to control your component. Good luck !

Comment: I did compare them, and it is the same. `render` is called when `setState` is called, even when I don't change the state (e.g. I set the same value into state). And this can happen both inside and outside of the component. In this case I cannot detect any difference with `componentWillUpdate`

Comment: Normally, your `Outer` only updates ` props` of the `Inner` and the `Inner` updates it's own states. You compare `nextProps` for `props` which `Outer` passsz to `Inner` and `nextState` for `states` in `Inner` itself.

Comment: Maybe, what you say is something that can often be true, but it is not always. I don't have that situation. I don't even have any props passing to `Inner`